# Using $(element).val(); with html entities.

Tags: php, jquery

Whenever a user inputs something for their user profile into the database with php I use a string filter that converts it into html entities.

When the user is editing their profile late .. not sure if I'm doing this correct. But I loop through all of my fields with php and set their subsequent "keys" which is the input name with the value that's in the db.

```
<?php php foreach ($usermeta as $key=>$value){ ?>
<script> $("<? echo $key; ?>").val("<? echo $val ;?>"); </script>
<?php } ?>
```

THIS WORKS GREAT. But the html entities don't get converted back? How do I do this? And is there a way to do it without breaking the jquery when you convern the html entities into apostrophes or commas?

I can't just echo each value into the input val because I have dropdowns in some cases and as far as I know... looping through your values via php and setting the value via jquery is the only way to set dropdowns.

Comment: Don't do this when storing the data into the database. _Store_ the raw data, as-is. Send it through the necessary handling functions (and that would rather be `htmlspechialchars` than `htmlentities`) when you _output_ it.

Comment: _"and as far as I know... looping through your values via php and setting the value via jquery is the only way to set dropdowns"_ - of course it isn't. PHP is perfectly capable of generating the necessary HTML output to create a select field, with certain option(s) preselected if desired.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the initial question, you need to [decode the entities][1] before echoing thing:

```
$("<? echo $key; ?>").val("<? echo(html_entity_decode($val)); ?>");
```

As far as whether doing it like this is a good idea, no, not really. When you output your form, you can set this directly in the input value like:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="<?php echo(html_entity_decode($usermeta->foo)); ?>">
```

Another option is to JSON encode your `$usermeta` and set that in script tags. Then let javascript update the fields.
[1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: But when i decode the entity in the .val();  I have to put single quotes like .val('   <?php echo $val;?>  '); and if I do html_entity_decode() and it converts the entities back to apostrophes it sees it as  .val(' mr o'grady '); and it breaks becuase of the single quote in the middle.  unless i'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

html_entity_decode function  in javascript

```js
let html_entity_decode = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/&#(x[0-9a-fA-F]+|\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec.substr(0, 1) == 'x' ? parseInt(dec.substr(1), 16) : dec);
  })
};
```

using for example

```
alert(html_entity_decode('&#39640;&#32423;&#31243;&#24207;&#35774;&#35745;'))
```